How to get value of std::formatter<std::chrono::zoned_time> to use repeatedly?
How to get value of std::formatter<std::chrono::zoned_time> to use repeatedly?
I need to be able to format time with the same format string repeatedly. I can't seem to figure out how to keep the std::formatter instance for this. The wiki suggests that it is usually not something that is done:

The std::formatter specialization is usually not directly accessed, but is used through formatting functions.

So, is it possible without hacks?

Why do you want to do this? The string should be parsed at compile time so you won't get better performance

@AlanBirtles The string is read from configuration. It is not a constant in code.

A [mre] would help

Use std::format_string.

If your only need is to "be able to format time with the same format string repeatedly", you can just construct a format string with the format then store it, and use std::vformat for zoned_time formatting every time:
#include <chrono>
#include <format>
#include <print>
#include <string>

using namespace std::literals;

int main() {
    auto date_fmt = "%D"s;
    auto runtime_fmt = std::format("{{:{}}}\n", date_fmt);
    auto time = std::chrono::zoned_time{};
    auto ret = std::vformat(runtime_fmt, std::make_format_args(time));
    std::print("{}", ret);
}

https://godbolt.org/z/9T63b1Efe
There's no need to store a std::formatter, and typically they are constructed by formatting functions directly using the formatting args.
